# MySQL ORDER BY Customized

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have these rows y DB and I would like order by but in the below order with caracters and number. The colum Score is a varchar. WINNER and LOSER are in Score colum also.

**Score**

```
WINNER
100+
100
90
80+
80
50
LOSER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach converts the `score` value to a number when ordering. I tried it with your data, then with your data plus additional values, and it worked both times:

```
SELECT score
FROM myTable
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN score = 'WINNER' THEN 100000
    WHEN score = 'LOSER' THEN -100000
    WHEN score LIKE '%+' THEN score * 100 + 99
    ELSE score * 100
 END DESC
```

The conversion is as follows:

- `WINNER` = 100,000
- `LOSER` = -100,000
- `number+` = number * 100 + 99
- `number` = number