# MySQL ORDER BY or GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

In relation to: [MySQL ORDER BY Customized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045230/mysql-order-by-customized)
I have another question.
We have an `id_competitor` with various scores.

```
id_competitor   score
1               WIN
2               50+
3               90+
4               90+
1               50
2               WIN
3               40
4               40+
```

I would like to use `order by` but in the following order:

```
id_competitor
2
1
4
3
```

I dont know how i should do it, with `SELECT DISTINCT with ORDER BY or GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on other answer, I would do something like

```
SELECT s.id_competitor 
FROM (
SELECT 
  id_competitor, 
  SUM(CASE
       WHEN score = 'WIN' THEN 100000
       WHEN score = 'LOSER' THEN -100000
       WHEN score LIKE '%+' THEN score * 100 + 99
       ELSE score * 100
       END) as score
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id_competitor) as s
ORDER BY s.score DESC
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93e5b/3)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Ed's excellent response ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/2091410/ed-gibbs )

```
select outside.id_competitor, sum(outside.numericscore) as sumscore
from (
select inside.id_competitor, CASE
    WHEN inside.score = 'WINNER' THEN 100000
    WHEN inside.score = 'LOSER' THEN -100000
    WHEN inside.score LIKE '%+' THEN inside.score * 100 + 99
    ELSE inside.score * 100
    END AS "numericscore" 
FROM mytable inside
) as outside
group by outside.id_competitor
order by sumscore desc
```